# How to create additional controls in WinAPI? Only the first control works?

Tags: c++, winapi, button

I've recently started to study WinAPI. After going through about ten top search results for tutorials on it, I'm still confused where you add code for more than one control per window? For example, if I want to add a second button, what kind of code and where do you place the code for it?

When I `#define IDC_BUTTON   WM_USER + 1`, add `HINSTANCE hIns;` and `HWND hButton;` to the Callback, and then call this:

```
case WM_CREATE:
    hIns=((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance;
    hButton=CreateWindow("Button","Click Me",WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,70,60,150,30,hwnd,(HMENU)IDC_BUTTON,hIns,0);
break;
```

It works and the button appears in the window. But when I try to add a second one, nothing appears, even with changed names:

`#define IDC_BUTTON2   WM_USER + 2`
+
`HINSTANCE hIns;`
`HWND hButton2;`

```
case WM_CREATE:
   hIns=((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance;
   hButton=CreateWindow("Button","Click Me",WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,70,60,150,30,hwnd,(HMENU)IDC_BUTTON,hIns,0);
   hButton2=CreateWindow("Second","Press here",WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,170,160,250,130,hwnd,(HMENU)IDC_BUTTON2,hIns,0);
   break;
```

The first button appears OK, but the second does not (different coordinates also). What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Edit:
I replaced the `hIns2` with `hIns` in the code.

Comment: Though it won't solve your problem, there is no need for `hIns2`, it will be the same as `hIns`

Comment: It looks OK, what is the size of the main window, perhaps your 2nd button is out of the dialog area?

Comment: The main window is 640 x 480. I also tried to resize the window manually (dragging from the side), but it wouldn't appear.

Comment: No need for hInst2 (as already mentioned).

Comment: @SChepurin, But the `HMENU` parameter is also used for the id of the child.

Comment: @chris - Corrected. Normally, it must work. There is nothing wrong in code.

Comment: Is there a window class called "Second" created by your code somewhere?  If not, that's the issue.

Comment: CreateWindow("Second" <--- change it to "BUTTON" unless you registered "Second" class.

Comment: noting wrong with the HMENU parameter, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477951/win32-api-create-button-help

Comment: @9dan and thang: Ah, hehe. That worked :) I forgot that it's defined by the class name. After changing the second CreateWindow() to "Button", too, it works just fine. Thank you! Both of you can post it as an answer, so I will accept them.

Comment: @JuhaUntinen, You can only accept one answer. Be prepared to choose someone's fate.

Comment: It is my destiny... While thang was the first to answer, it was 9dan's answer that made it clear for me, so I shall choose that answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
 hButton2=CreateWindow("Second","Press here",WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,...);
```

Let's tackle this at the core.  The fundamental thing you are doing wrong is completely ignoring the need to check for errors.  CreateWindow() returns NULL when it failed.  GetLastError() then returns an error code that indicates the problem.  That same error code is also visible in a debugger with the "@err" pseudo variable.

You would then quickly have discovered that you got error 1407, described like this in the WinError.h SDK header:

```
//
// MessageId: ERROR_CANNOT_FIND_WND_CLASS
//
// MessageText:
//
// Cannot find window class.
//
#define ERROR_CANNOT_FIND_WND_CLASS      1407L
```

Which makes it crystal clear that you flubbed the class name in the CreateWindow() call.

**Never** skip error checks, especially when you are just starting out with winapi programming.  It isn't just useful to let programs graciously fail when things go wrong on the user's machine, it is clearly also extremely useful to diagnose bugs in your code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no class name called `"SECOND` unless you defined one already so if you want to make say 10 buttons the first parameter in the `CreateWindow` function is going to be `"BUTTON"` in all of them, you can also change it to `"EDIT"` if you want an editable text box or `"STATIC"` if you ant to put a static box.
Secondly you can make a process of adding buttons alot more easier if you followed this note:

Instead of defining your button by making
`#define IDB_BUTTON WM_USER + 2`
and then inserting the `IDB_BUTTON` into the `CreateWindow` function as `(HMENU)IDB_BUTTON`
you can simply just write `(HMENU)<any number of your choice>` in to the CreateWindow function just like `(HMENU) 2` without needing to predefine that number using `#define` and then when you want to make an action when the button is pressed you can just pass that number in a case of a switch statement that has `(LOWORD(wParam))` as its switch .

It seems confusing but see the code to understand what i mean

full code in your procedure:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch(Msg)
{
case WM_CREATE:
hButton=CreateWindow("Button","Click Me",WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,70,60,150,30,hWnd,(HMENU) 1,NULL,NULL);
hButton2=CreateWindow("BUTTON","Press here",WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,170,160,250,130,hwnd,(HMENU) 2,NULL,NULL);
break;
case WM_COMMAND:
switch(LOWORD(wParam))
{
case 1:
//What will the first button do?write it here
break;
case 2:
//What will the second button do?write it here
break;
}
    break;
}
return 0;
}
```

Good luck on your path studying win32 c++ i remember when i started also it was confusing and it is still for me but by hard work you will master it

;)